# Detecting whether the computer is a Domain Controller

Tags: api, winapi, domaincontroller

How do I get information whether the system is configured as domain controller or not programatically on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the HKLM read, [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s `OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType` will equal `VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER`

Answer (score 1):

Examine the registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ProductOptions\ProductType.  A domain controller will have the value LanmanNT.  [LINK](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=152078)